# Google Places API query 'opennow=true' returns 0 results (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, google-maps, google-places-api

I am querying the Google Places API with the following set-up:

- **Backend:** [Radar Search Request](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#RadarSearchRequests) via post-route (using Express and 'request'-module in Node.js)
- **Frontend:** Display results on map, querying Place Detail request after clicking on marker icon [(example from API documentation as reference)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details)

All works fine, except that my search request doesn't seem to pass on my restriction of 'only places currently open' via 'opennow=true' within search request. There are surely restaurants open in Amsterdam at the time I send this request, I manually checked it on GoogleMaps. I've been trying all different ways of spelling and searched for similar solutions, but can't find the problem. Any help very much appreciated, thank you.

**Code for reference:**

```js
app.post('/results', function(req,res){

 //PARAMETERS FOR SEARCH QUERY FOR RESTAURANTS, OPEN NOW
 const baseurl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?';
 const location = 'location=52.370216,4.895168';
 const radius = 'radius=5000';
 const type = 'type=food';
 const key = 'key='+process.env.googleapikey;

 // const opennow = 'openNow=true'; //doesn't narrow down results, doesn't seem to get applied
 // const opennow2 = 'open_now=true'; //doesn't narrow down results, doesn't seem to get applied
 const opennow3 = 'opennow=true'; //0 search results returned, doesn't seem to work

 const queryurl = `${baseurl}${location}&${radius}&${type}&${key}&${opennow3}`;

 //SEARCH QUERY TO GOOGLE PLACES API, USING REQUEST MODULE
 request({
  uri: queryurl,
  method: "GET",
  timeout: 10000,
  followRedirect: true,
  maxRedireccts: 10
  }, function(err, response, body) {

   var allresults = [];

   if(err){
    console.log(err);
   } else {
    
    var responseparsed = JSON.parse(body);
    var results = responseparsed.results;

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
     allresults.push(results[i]);
    } 
    console.log('Maps found >'+results.length+'< results');
   } 
   res.render("results", {allresults: allresults, mapsjsapikey: mapsjsapikey});
  }
 )
});
```

Comment: I don't know node.js but I think you ought to know that Places API Radar Search has just been deprecated, and will be retired in a year. Please see full details at https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html

Comment: Thank you @miguev - that's sad news for my project! Good to know anyways.. :)